# Corda Spring Boot start tracked flow Unknown constant pool tag

Tags: spring-boot, corda

If you wire up a spring boot application to connect to a party via rpc (in this case to the IOU sample Party A), are you not able to use the result from a tracked flow because of some synchronization issues?

1. I just copied the jar file for the IOU cordapp that was produced for Party A for the flow dependencies.  This could be a mistake.
2. I'm thinking in a production environment I probably wouldn't want to block during a request anyway, but thought I would give this a go.

Here's the code:

```
val signedTx = rpcOps.startTrackedFlow(ExampleFlow::Initiator, iouValue, otherParty).returnValue.getOrThrow()
ResponseEntity.status(CREATED).body("Transaction id ${signedTx.id} committed to ledger.\n")
```

Currently the transaction goes through just fine from the first line of code above, but I get a stack trace on the next line that includes grabbing the id from the signedTx.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown constant pool tag [I@576ae80a in classfile module-info.class (element size unknown, cannot continue reading class. Please report this on the FastClasspathScanner GitHub page.
    at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.FastClasspathScanner.scan(FastClasspathScanner.java:1408) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
    at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.FastClasspathScanner.scan(FastClasspathScanner.java:1439) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
    at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.FastClasspathScanner.scan(FastClasspathScanner.java:1462) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme$Companion$customSerializers$2.invoke(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:41) ~[corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme$Companion$customSerializers$2.invoke(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:35) ~[corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:131) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.21.jar:1.2.21-release-88 (1.2.21)]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme$Companion.getCustomSerializers(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt) ~[corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme$Companion.access$getCustomSerializers$p(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:35) ~[corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.registerCustomSerializers(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:87) ~[corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.getSerializerFactory(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:118) ~[corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.deserialize(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:122) ~[corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66) ~[corda-core-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86) ~[corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80) ~[corda-core-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction.getCoreTransaction(SignedTransaction.kt:272) ~[corda-core-corda-3.0.jar:na]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction.getId(SignedTransaction.kt:55) ~[corda-core-corda-3.0.jar:na]

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown constant pool tag [I@5c774621 in classfile module-info.class (element size unknown, cannot continue reading class. Please report this on the FastClasspathScanner GitHub page.
    at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.utils.InterruptionChecker.executionException(InterruptionChecker.java:74) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
    at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.utils.WorkQueue.runWorkLoop(WorkQueue.java:142) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
    at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.utils.WorkQueue$1.call(WorkQueue.java:99) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
    at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.utils.WorkQueue$1.call(WorkQueue.java:96) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Called close() before completing all work units
        at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.utils.WorkQueue.close(WorkQueue.java:194) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
        at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.scanner.Scanner.call(Scanner.java:384) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
        at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.scanner.Scanner.call(Scanner.java:59) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
        ... 4 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unreleased instances: 3
        at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.utils.Recycler.close(Recycler.java:69) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
        at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.scanner.Scanner.call(Scanner.java:384) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
        at io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.scanner.Scanner.call(Scanner.java:59) ~[fast-classpath-scanner-2.0.21.jar:2.0.21]
        ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Which Gradle version are you using?

Comment: Gradle 4.1 - included with the IOU sample.  The spring boot application is using Maven.

Comment: Does this still happen if you unsubscribe from the flow handle's observable before returning? `FlowHandle.progress.unsubscribe()`.

Comment: @joel
I updated my code but still encounter the same error when I try to access the signed transaction data:


`val flowHandle = rpcOps.startTrackedFlow(::Initiator, iouValue, otherParty)`  


`val subscribe = flowHandle.progress.subscribe()`  


`val signedTransaction = flowHandle.returnValue.getOrThrow()`  


`subscribe.unsubscribe()`  


`logger.debug(signedTransaction.toString())`

Comment: Here is the github link to my repo: https://github.com/bret540/corda-iou-spring-boot

Comment: Thanks. What do I have to run to reproduce the issue?

Comment: once you've done everything in the readme (including running the spring boot application) and posted a sample request to the spring boot application, it will use rpc to connect to the IOU party A node and during that processing is where I saw the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that is fixed in Corda 3.1.

It was due to a bug in the version of the `FastClasspathScanner` library that Corda 3.0 used.

Comment: Thanks @joel, I'll try this again when 3.1 is out and update this as the accepted answer when it works!